# JS using a closure replicate an private set object only available through get/accessor method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that uses a closure to replicate an object.

accessing the getter property within a private function.

```
 function Container(param) {
      var person = {
      firstName: 'Jimmy',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      get fullName() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      },
    set fullName (name) {
       var words = name.toString().split(' ');
       this.firstName = words[0] || '';
       this.lastName = words[1] || '';
   }
  }
 }

  // Attempting to clone private getter don't know how to access it.

     function objectClone(person) {

       var orginal = person //Trying to access the private method

       var clone = function cloneObj { Object.assign({}, original); }

       clone.prototype.spillSecret = function() { alert(this.getfullName()); }

     ;}
```

Comment: Neither of your functions makes any sense. For example why are you creating a person object that is neither referenced nor returned from `Container` function? `objectClone` doesn't return anything. `cloneObj` neither returns nor affects `original` object (other than calling getter which might have some side-effects but usually doesn't)

Comment: I agree the original question's concept was hard for me to grasp, I thought I had to clone a regular object with Object.assign, that's the reason why I created the person object to try to set the getter properties within that object. All in all in my attempt I have no idea how to structure so the getter properties are private and clone method only copies those private properties.

Comment: `get fullName` != `getfullName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to create a new *instance* of a `Container`. Firstly, we should fix up that code:

```
function Container(param) {
  this.firstName = 'Jimmy';
  this.lastName = 'Smith';
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set: function(name) {
      var words = name.toString().split(' ');
      this.firstName = words[0] || '';
      this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
  });
}
```

Now, to create a new `Container` object, we use `new`:

```
var person = new Container();
```

`person` will have the `get` and `set` methods for `fullName` on it.

Comment: Thank you so from above, do I tie in the same cloning function I attempted originally basically how would I copy the full name property.

Comment: You use the `person` object you just created: `var person = new Container(); person.fullName = 'John Doe'; console.log('person.firstName');` => `John`

Comment: Thank you! I've updated your answer and accept it, just making sure I have it correct.